# Extracting responses from random samples in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to do a load test where I have a request that returns a set of URLs in the response. I want to parse the response, extract these URLs from the response and make requests to *x%* of them.

For example, say I am load testing an endpoint called /test-something. When I hit the /test-something endpoint, I get *m* number of URLs in the response. For all the responses that I get back from the /test-something endpoint, I want to parse them and extract *x%* of the URLs and in turn make request to those *x%* URLs. I am also okay if there's a way to parse, extract and write those *x%* URLs in a file. I can then just run a post script that will parse these URLs from the file and make requests to them.

Please note that I expect all responses to have pretty much the same number of URLs in it.

I can think about doing it one of two ways. Either parse only *x%* of response samples or parse each response sample but extract only *x%* of the URLs.

Is there a way to do either of the above in Jmeter?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach I can think of is:

1. Extract **all** the URLs and save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), if you configure i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor) like this:

   [image]

   you will get JMeter Variables like:

   ```
   URL_1=http://example.com
   URL_2=http://jmeter.apache.org
   etc
   URL_matchNr=the number of extracted URLs
   ```

   [image]
2. Once you have this number you can calculate the required percentage from it, using i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) and add a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate the extracted URLs desired number of times.